# Copying STL files to gazebo_worlds

Tags: ros, stl, gazebo-worlds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

How do I copy a file into gazebo_worlds, currently I am trying the following command

$ cp table.stl `rospack find gazebo_worlds`/Media/models/

but I get returned the message

cp: cannot create regular file `/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/Media/models/table.stl : Permission denied

I understand that I am not able to change the gazebo folders. Is there a way around this? Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30408/copying-stl-files-to-gazebo_worlds/) by [alexanderjyuen](https://answers.ros.org/users/2045/alexanderjyuen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is because you installed ros from .debs and do not have write permissions for the directories of this installation variant. You could force changes by using "sudo" before your commands or changing permissions, but this is strongly discouraged. For example, you might lose all your changes if a update comes in for a package you modified.

If you want to make your own gazebo worlds or variants of existing ones, you can create a new package and use that. I did exactly that with the [hector_gazebo_worlds](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_gazebo_worlds) package, so it's the first one that comes to my mind as an example. You'll probably find a few other examples if you search for them.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4